# Python DataFrame chunk extract issue

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, python-requests

I want to divide a data frame into chunks (eg: if we have 100 rows, I divide them as 20 chunks) and for each chunk with 5 values in it, I need to apply 5 update queries(5 different tables) on this chunked data.

How can I achieve this task, as am new to this and learning as I work, could you suggest the approach for this ?

```
for item in np.array_split(df1, 10):
 print(item) ##I was able to divide into chunks
 for i,j in item.iterrows():
   print(item.iloc[i]['ColumnName'])
```

My idea is to add the update query line after this print statement.

But this code gives an exception.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/gd/Documents/myproj/test.py", line 63, in <module>
    func()
  File "/Users/gd/Documents/myproj/test.py", line 45, in dedupe_pe
    print(item.iloc[i]['ColumnName'])
  File "/Users/gd/Documents/myproj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 931, in __getitem__
    return self._getitem_axis(maybe_callable, axis=axis)
  File "/Users/gd/Documents/myproj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1566, in _getitem_axis
    self._validate_integer(key, axis)
  File "/Users/gd/Documents/myproj/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pandas/core/indexing.py", line 1500, in _validate_integer
    raise IndexError("single positional indexer is out-of-bounds")
IndexError: single positional indexer is out-of-bounds
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`item.iterrows()` yields a row index, and row itself, so you could try as follows:

```
for item in np.array_split(df1, 10):
    print(item) ##I was able to divide into chunks
    item["sql"] = "UPDATE " + item["table_name"] + " SET column1 = '" + item["ColumnName_DATA"] + "' WHERE condition"
    for i, j in item.iterrows():
        print(j['ColumnName'])
        print(j['sql'])
```

Comment: ok, it's working. One more thing, Can we convert the chunk into a list and use this list for some operations?

Comment: @George If you only want internal values of the chunk, just use `item.values` instead of `item.iterrows()`.

Comment: for item in np.array_split(df1, 10):
    print(item) ##I was able to divide into chunks -> assume count of 5 data is there inside each chunk
    for i, j in item.iterrows():
        print(j['ColumnName'])
        UPDATE table_name1 SET column1 = <ColumnName_DATA1> WHERE condition;
        UPDATE table_name2 SET column1 = <ColumnName_DATA2> WHERE condition;
        UPDATE table_name3 SET column1 = <ColumnName_DATA3> WHERE condition;
        UPDATE table_name4 SET column1 = <ColumnName_DATA4> WHERE condition;
        UPDATE table_name5 SET column1 = <ColumnName_DATA5> WHERE condition;

Comment: something like above i wanted to achieve

Comment: @George Your comments are difficult to understand, but anyway I updated the answer.